# Datatable Select for Timespan Value

Tags: select, datatable, timespan

I tried to compare a SQL Server based Datatable with a time(7) Column, with a timespan Value:

```
ds.exdatable.Select("TimeColumn ='" & extimespanvalue.ToString & "'")
```

But this is not possible ..., then I tried to convert the TimeSpan Value:

```
ds.exdatable.Select("TimeColumn =Convert('" & extimespanvalue.ToString & "',System.TimeSpan)")
```

Getting an exception can't convert String to TimeSpan. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there no solution out there?

Comment: I filed a bug - I recommend you upvote: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806804/datatable-select-unable-to-convert-string-to-timespan-net-framework-4